# Would it be possible to use Apache Chainsaw viewer in my Java project that's in Eclipse?

Tags: apache-chainsaw

I'm wondering if [Chainsaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/) is too old for Eclipse? The java project i'm working on is using JDK 1.5 .

Does it need to be compatible with Eclipse? because I did find another log -viewer called [LogViewer](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/logviewer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chainsaw V2 is a standalone app that can be used with JDK 1.5 just fine - if you mean using a socketappender, assuming the version of log4j you are sending with matches the version Chainsaw uses (log4j 1.2.x).

If you don't want to use a socketappender, you can use a fileappender - it's much easier - in the Chainsaw config screen, point it to your log4j.properties or log4j.xml containing a fileappender, and it will build the correct configuration to tail your log file.

The Chainsaw V2 available from the website is really old - the latest Chainsaw V2 developer snapshot is available here: http://people.apache.org/~sdeboy

Comment: Hi, I'm revisiting this. when you say `build the correct configuration to tail your log file`  what does that mean? thanks!

Comment: If you have a log4j.xml or log4j.properties files which contains a FileAppender entry for a log file you would like to have Chainsaw tail, download the latest developer snapshot of Chainsaw from the link above, select the File-Load Chainsaw configuration menu, select the 'Use fileappender entries' option, click 'open file' to browse to your log4j.xml or log4j.properties file, click the 'always start Chainsaw with this config' checkbox and press OK.  You should get a new tab in Chainsaw containing the log file contents from the fileappender.  Chainsaw will tail that log file.